# KVM bad IO sync performance in Linux guest

Tags: virtualization, performance, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, io

I'm setting up virtualized Ubuntu 15.10 guest inside Ubuntu 15.04 server using libvirt and KVM.

Storage in host system:

```
# mount | grep ext4
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/hdd type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
```

*/dev/sda* is an SSD and */dev/sdb* is a HDD.

The initial configuration was done using virt-manager.

**Problem:**

Overall performance of guest system seems to be good, however some operations, noticeably installing packages using apt-get (and therefore guest system installation) are very slow.

Guest disk image is in raw format, and I've tried placing it on both SSD and HDD as a file, and also as a separate partition on HDD. Different locations make some difference on performance, however installing some package using apt-get is still two or three times slower than on host system.

I've also tried various qemu disk cache options, **and using *unsafe* cache seems to eliminate the problem completely**. But, any other cache setting, including *none* and *writeback* shows bad performance. Of course, using unsafe doesn't look like a real solution.

Here is an excerpt from the guest xml config:

```
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
  <source dev='/dev/sdb2'/>
  <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
  <boot order='2'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x09' function='0x0'/>
</disk>
```

When using image file instead of a partition that becomes:

```
<disk type='file' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
  <source file='/media/hdd/dsi/vm/ubuntu4.bin'/>
  <backingStore/>
  <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
  <boot order='2'/>
  <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
</disk>
```

While trying to fix the issue, I've noticed that the first partition on the HDD was not properly aligned, so I re-created the partition with correct alignment (which for this HDD is 4096). This also hasn't helped much.

I've also tried setting elevator=noop for the guest, to no avail.

When I run similar guest system on Windows PC using VirtualBox, I don't experience such performance degradation, so I hope there's a way to run the guest with the same performance on KVM also.

Comment: Have you tried with `io='threads'`? Note that in raw QEMU this parameter is called `aio`, isn't this a typo or a bug in libvirt?

Comment: @sam_pan_mariusz Yes, I did try io=threads, no noticeable difference. The parameter *io* is passed as *aio* to qemu command line, so no mistake here.

Comment: Have you tried comparing benchmarks made with ie. *iozone3* from both host and guest (direct partition makes most sense)? This could tell us much about the problem scale. And what about host CPU utilization during IO-intensive guest operations (can be chacked during the benchmars)?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
cache=directsync
```

Or

```
cache=writethrough
```

Also

```
vm.swappiness=1
vm.vfs_cache_pressure=75 (play around with this)
```

Use deadline instead of cfq/noop (poor performers on ssds and raid I've found).

Ignore what people say about cache=none or writeback being the best. It not always that simple.